# nodejs module - express module.export - how to pass variable to other file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Question is how to pass variable to other js file in the simplest way (without any routes just with module.exports).

My file structure looks like this (very simple popular structure):

```
ROUTES (folder)
--form.js
--test.js

VIEWS (folder)
--form.ejs
--test.ejs

index.js
package.json
```

index.js file (standard express app file):

```
var express = require('express');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');

var form = require('./routes/form.js');
var test = require('./routes/test.js');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.use('/', form);
app.use('/test', test);

var port = 3700;
var server_listen_on = app.listen(port, function()
{
    console.log('Server is listening on port: ' + port);
});
```

form.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var body_parser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();

var preciousData = 'var precious_data - from form.js file';

module.exports =
{
    exportsPreciousData : preciousData,
    router : router
};
```

test.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var router = express.Router();

var requireFormjs = require('./form.js');//({exportsPreciousData : exportsPreciousData});


//console.log(requireFormjs.exportsPreciousData); // I guess console.log is faster then module.exports... but

router.get('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    res.render('welcome', {test : requireFormjs.exportsPreciousData});
});

// why this doesn't work - I need to use middleware function - could you provide simple working example?
//(I guessing that even if console.log print data after module.exports machinery I would still need middleware, right?)

module.exports = router;
```

welcome.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>welcome</title>

</head>
<body>

<%= test %>

</body>
</html>
```

... why it's not working (without express everything runs fine)?

Answer (score 0):

Simple make those other files return a function:

Test.js:

```
module.exports = function(preciousData) {
  // do everything here
  return router;
}
```

index.js:

```
var test = require('test.js')(preciousData);
```

Data is passed by calling the function that `test.js` returns and router is returned from that function